# Is there a way to connect Google sheets to MySQL(phpmyadmin )

Tags: php, database, google-sheets, phpmyadmin

So I have a Google sheet (is not mine) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bJWIwNPGa1nz5pO8TZMir4eh6p32YwFG6IgHPFt3PDI/pubhtml?gid=4&single=true&widget=false&headers=false&chrome=false    and I want to insert in new database and  to get update each day. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. You can use Google Apps Script for this.

I recommend you go through the documentation about the [JDBC service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#other_databases) on how to connect to external DB from Apps Script.

Also, you want to fetch data from that sheet, but it appears the owner does not permit copying it or downloading it, so you should get authorization to at least download, that way you could open it with Apps Script and use the [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) to get the data from the sheet and pass it using JDBC to your MySQL instance.

**Further reading:**
- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview)

Answer (score 0):

For daily refreshes, you might want to look into [simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers). Google places some hard limits however, like 20 Triggers / user / script. You can learn more about that [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).

If you don't want to build your own solution, you can use database connector addons, like Castodia, Seekwell, Kpibees, and so on. You can find them [here](https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/search/database%20connector). Most of them support auto refreshes, but I can only speak of [Castodia](https://www.castodia.com/) since I was involved in building that addon. Its backend does not use simple triggers, so there are no limits on number of triggers or sheets.